# Invalid DO loop control information in SAS Base

Tags: sas, hashtable, proc-sql

I need to find for every row the last 3hr usage (Usage is one of the columns in dataset) grouped by User and ID_option. 
Every line(row) represent one record (within 3 min time interval). For example (including desired column sum_usage_3hr):

```
User  ID_option          time             usage        sum_usage_3hr
1         a1        12OCT2017:11:20:32       3             10
1         a1        12OCT2017:10:23:24       7             14
1         b1        12OCT2017:09:34:55       12            12
2         b1        12OCT2017:08:55:06       4              6
1         a1        12OCT2017:07:59:53       7              7
2         b1        12OCT2017:06:59:12       2              2
```

I have used code below for hash table:

```
data want;
 if _n_=1 then do;
  if 0 then set have(rename=(usage=_usage));
  declare hash h(dataset:'have(rename=(usage=_usage))',hashexp:20);
  h.definekey('user','id_option','time');
  h.definedata('_usage');
  h.definedone();
 end;
set have;
sum_usage_3hr=0;
do i=time-3*3600 to time ;
 if h.find(key:user,key:id_option,key:i)=0 then sum_usage_3hr+_usage;
end;
drop _usage i;
run;
```

But I got an error: Invalid DO loop control information, either the INITIAL or TO expression is missing or the BY expression is missing, zero, or invalid. If I add:
output;
end:
just above the "run;" it gives me an error: 'No matching DO/Select statement'.
Anybody know what causes the problem? 
I have also the version with sorting the table firstly and gives me the same error. 
Thank you

After implementing the for answer:

```
User  ID_option          time             usage   sum_usage_3hr   col_i_got
1         a1        12OCT2017:11:22:32       3         12             3      
1         a1        12OCT2017:11:20:24       0          9             3
1         a1        12OCT2017:10:34:55       2          9             2
1         a1        12OCT2017:09:55:06       0          7             2
1         a1        12OCT2017:09:43:45       0          7             0
1         a1        12OCT2017:08:59:53       7          7             7
1         a1        12OCT2017:06:59:12       0          0             7
```

Comment: Is the time variable stored as a number or as a string?

Comment: @user2877959 It's stored in a format datetime.

Comment: that is not an answer my question. In SAS there are only two types of variables: number and character. Which is it? While _"stored in a format datetime"_ doesn't mean anything in SAS; it could be interpreted as you meaning either that it is stored as a number with a datetime format applied to it, or that it is stored as the character representation of a datetime formatted value. If it is stored as a number, your do loop is fine. If it is stored as a character, your do loop is obviously invalid (subtracting a number from a string) and that error message is the what you would get in that case.

Comment: @user2877959 What I wrote a program for loading data in input I include: TIME :anydtdtm23., that's all. I assume it's a string?

Comment: If you using INPUT with numeric format like ANYDTDTM. then you are creating a numeric variable. Character formats start with a $.  How the value is displayed depends on what format you attach to the variable with a FORMAT statement, or use in your PUT statement or PUT() function call.

Comment: Then it is indeed numeric. I ran your code on your sample data and it ran perfectly. Did you check whether or not you have missing values for the time variable in your actual data? When you get your error message there should also be a line that gives you the values of some variables at the moment the error occured. What does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

***Problem 1:***

**Input:**

```
data have;
input User  ID_option  $        time            usage    ;
informat time datetime18.;
format time datetime18.;
cards;
1         a1        12OCT2017:11:20:32       3
1         a1        12OCT2017:10:23:24       7
1         b1        12OCT2017:09:34:55       12
2         b1        12OCT2017:08:55:06       4
1         a1        12OCT2017:07:59:53       7
2         b1        12OCT2017:06:59:12       2
;
run;
```

**Code:**

```
proc sort data=have out=have1;
by user id_option time;
quit;

data have2;
set have1;
by user id_option;
format previous_time datetime18.;
previous_time = lag(time);
previous_usage = lag(usage);
if first.ID_option then previous_time=.;
if previous_time ~= . and intnx("hour",time,-3,"s") <= previous_time <= time then sum_usage_3hr=usage+previous_usage; 
else sum_usage_3hr = usage;
drop previous_time previous_usage;
run;

proc sort data=have2 out=want;
by descending time ;
quit;
```

**Output:**

```
 User   ID_option   time    usage   sum_usage_3hr
    1   a1  12Oct2017 11:20:32  3   10
    1   a1  12Oct2017 10:23:24  7   14
    1   b1  12Oct2017 9:34:55   12  12
    2   b1  12Oct2017 8:55:06   4   6
    1   a1  12Oct2017 7:59:53   7   7
    2   b1  12Oct2017 6:59:12   2   2
```

***Problem2:***

**Input:**

```
data have;
input user1  ID_option  $        time            usage    ;
informat time datetime18.;
format time datetime18.;
cards;
1         a1        12OCT2017:11:22:32       3
1         a1        12OCT2017:11:20:24       0
1         a1        12OCT2017:10:34:55       2
1         a1        12OCT2017:09:55:06       0
1         a1        12OCT2017:09:43:45       0
1         a1        12OCT2017:08:59:53       7
1         a1        12OCT2017:06:59:12       0
;
run;
```

**Code:**

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select user1,id_option,time,min(usage) as usage,sum(usage1) as sum_usage_3hr
from
(
select a.*,b.time as time1 ,b.usage as usage1
from
have a
left join
have b
on a.user1 = b.user1 and a.id_option = b.id_option and b.time <= a.time
where  intck("hour",a.time ,b.time) >= -3
)
group by 1,2,3
order by time desc;
quit;
```

**Output:**

```
user1   ID_option   time    usage   sum_usage_3hr
1   a1  12Oct2017 11:22:32  3   12
1   a1  12Oct2017 11:20:24  0   9
1   a1  12Oct2017 10:34:55  2   9
1   a1  12Oct2017 9:55:06   0   7
1   a1  12Oct2017 9:43:45   0   7
1   a1  12Oct2017 8:59:53   7   7
1   a1  12Oct2017 6:59:12   0   0
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: An output is good on the sample, but on real data, it's not, because I got a bunch of rows where usage is 0, and the code does not calculate for rows where usage is 0 except row below the row where is the usage. I will edit my question so you can see a sample of the output.

Comment: When i run your code(for both the queries), no such error occurs, it works perfectly!!

Comment: I find the problem, but not the solution. I have some missing values in columns : Time and Usage. Just a few rows out of million. :/

Comment: Thank you, I've almost finished my task. :)

Comment: Happy to help!! Incase you used any other approach do update it.